# Assigning a value from a dataframe to a dynamically created variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a simple pandas dataframe with a column 'mycol' and has 5 rows in it and I'm trying to create 5 new variables for every row value, something like below:

```
newcol_1=df['mycol'][0]
newcol_2=df['mycol'][1]
newcol_3=df['mycol'][2]
newcol_4=df['mycol'][3]
newcol_5=df['mycol'][4]
```

I don't want to hard code as above and I'm using the below "for loop" but it keeps throwing 'can't assign to operator'.  I know that assignment values should be on the right and variable on the left but not sure how do I use for loop to dynamically create these 5 variables.

```
for i in 0, df.shape[0]-1:
    #"newcol_"+str(i+1) =df['mycol'][i]  # this isn't working
    newcol_+str(i+1) =df['mycol'][i]     # this also isn't working
```

Appreciate if anyone can help with this...Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) answer your question?

Comment: Why don't you create a list or dictionary for the variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preferred option: modify [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

```py
# Create variables dynamically 
for i, value in enumerate(df["VALUE"].values):
    globals()[f"newcol_{i+1}"] = value
```

```py
# Test that newcol_3 exists, for instance
print(newcol_3)  # Works fine
print(newcol_3 == df['mycol'][2])  # True
```

#### Alternate option: use [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Though one should do so [with caution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/11246056)

```py
# Create a new dict with desired key/value pairs
newcols = {f"newcol_{i+1}": value for i, value in enumerate(df["VALUE"].values)}

# Create new variables dynamically from dict
for name, value in newcols.items():
    exec(f"{name}= {value}")

# Previous tests work just as fine
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent. You are close...But, what I want is these new 5 variables as newcol1, newcol2,...newcol5 and not as subscript like newcol[1],newcol[2]...newcol[5]. I'm creating these 5 variables as placeholders and will be passing onto my next program so don't want to create a list or dictionary of variables...

Comment: Thanks..it worked although it's little complex than I thought and also remember reading online about using "exec" cautiously. Anyway, for now, it works and if anyone has any other simple solution that would be great.

Comment: Great...Thank you for your personal attention and time.